# How to ensure ignoreCase option is set for all team members?

Tags: git

My team use git as main source control tool. The git repositories are hosted by Azure Dev Ops.

Most of the teammate are working on windows but some are on ubuntu (Ubuntu os or through WSL, or from continuous delivery pipelines).

By default, on windows, git ignore case (`core.ignorecase` is `true` on default on windows) and its causing troubles, because `import 'Somefile.ts'` where the filename is actually `SomeFile.ts` works on windows, but not on other systems.

And renaming the file, just by changing casing is not considered as a change by git unless the `ignoreCase` option is set to `false`.

Is there any way to enforce this attributes for all team mates, at repository level (meaning the option is set on the main repo, and applied when cloning) ?

Setting this option using `git config core.ignorecase false` is local only.

Nothing in the [.gitattributes documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) seems to handle this requirement.

Comment: You cannot ensure it centrally; one have to run the command locally, that's the only way.

Comment: I would advice a completely different approach to the problem — switch from DoubleCase to all_lower_case_with_underscores. The style can be ensured centrally with a `pre-receive` or `pre-update` hooks — check the list of file names in every push and reject the push if casing/naming is wrong.

Comment: I don't get the suggestion you made, naming convention is highly driven by the technologies and language. That said, I'd check if I can set the option in one the git hooks

Comment: "*I'd check if I can set the option in one the git hooks*" Per my 1st comment — you cannot.

Comment: Git itself can't do it. But if you run some kind of build tool, you can probably configure that to check the git config during some initial task (or some frequently run task, so that isn't done permanently, but still likely to be caught). For example if you use `npm build` to build your software, make *that* verify that git is correctly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*about that point :*

> And renaming the file, just by changing casing is not considered as a change by git unless the `ignoreCase` option is set to `false`

I would invite you to test it on a case sensitive file system :
on my linux box, even with the `core.ignoreCase` option on, case changes in file names *are* registered.

What I do get is git ignoring `foo.txt` when it sits next to versioned `Foo.txt`, for example.

---

There is a gotcha on case insensitive filesystems (e.g : Windows and MacOS) :   `mv myfile.txt MyFile.txt` is treated as a noop *by the system itself*.

A common workaround is to do the rename in two steps, using a temporary name :

```
mv myfile.txt tmpname
mv tmpname MyFile.txt
git add myfile.txt MyFile.txt

# or
git mv myfile.txt tmpname
git mv tmpname MyFile.txt
```

---

*about your repo :*

as said by @phd and @knittl : you can't enforce a setting on every local clone. You can :

- commit some form of `setup.sh` script, to set up the local configuration of each developper PC
- use hooks on the central repo to reject commits that don't adhere to some rule

Additionally :

- you can add a CI builder which would test your code (if run on a case sensitive file system, it would hit the bugs you mention)
- you should look into linters that could catch this kind of bug
- in the would be `setup.sh` script, you can add hooks (`pre-commit` and/or `pre-push`) to run linters on the client side

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 100% ensure it, but you can add a simple script (.sh or .bat) to set this configuration for the repo. Each team member must run this script once after cloning the repository. Describe how to run it in your README or CONTRIBUTING files.

Answer (score 0):

Do not lie to Git.

The `core.ignorecase` (or `core.ignoreCase`<sup>1</sup>) setting tells Git *how your operating system behaves*.<sup>2</sup>  It does not *change* how your OS behaves, because it can't: it just allows Git to foretell, in advance, whether creating and writing to a file named `README.txt` is going to overwrite another file named `readme.txt`, or create a new separate `README.txt`.

If you do lie to Git, Git will behave in a file-system-incorrect manner, but in a predictable way (with the exact details depending on Git version).  This is occasionally useful to work around particular issues.  So you'll sometimes see StackOverflow answers that say "to work around this, fiddle with core.ignorecase, do operation X, then restore core.ignorecase".  *Some* of these answers fail to mention that you must *restore* the setting afterwards, but it is important to restore the setting afterwards.

The reason `core.ignorecase` exists is so that Git will behave better on systems that ignore case.  Over time, as the Git software evolves, these "behave better" behaviors should improve, although it can never be *perfect* because there's a fundamental mismatch here: *Git itself does not ignore case internally* and Git can always store two different files under names like `README.txt` vs `readme.txt`.  Anyone who uses Git *on* a *case-sensitive* file system, such as those found in most Linux installations, will be able to create and commit *both files* into a *single commit*.  If you're working on a system that *can't* extract both files at the same time, you can't work with this single commit in a completely-sensible manner (though as always there are various tricks and workarounds).

---

<sup>1</sup>Ironically, while Git is case-sensitive in *most* parts, it's case-*in* sensitive when looking at the first and last components of settings like these.  That is, both the words `core` and `ignorecase` can be spelled with arbitrary upper and lower casing, to some extent.  (I say "to some extent" because you can't, for instance, replace a German eszett `ß` with `SS`, even though that's a case-insensitive equivalent.  The uppercase ẞ did not exist until recently, but would generally work here, depending on your Unicode tables and the behavior of `tolower` in your C library.  Git doesn't have any of its own settings using `ß`, but as the `.gitconfig` file is user-extensible, you could add your own.)

Note that middle sections can be case-sensitive.  In particular `url.<thing>.insteadOf` *must* be case-sensitive in the middle since URLs themselves are generally case-sensitive (the URL is passed over the network to a different computer—the server—and it's the *server* that decides whether the URL is case-sensitive, and on many servers it is).

<sup>2</sup>Technically the behavior tends to be per-file-system, on modern operating systems, rather than OS-wide.  For instance, you can mount an old-style DOS 8.3 floppy, if you can find an old floppy, on Linux using a DOS-FS file system, and you'll get the silly eight-dot-three style file names.  Git assumes consistent behavior throughout the *working tree* of a repository, though, and probes the behavior at `git init` or `git clone` time to *set* `core.ignorecase`—Git spells it in all-lower-case when setting it up initially—based on the observed behavior.